# Problems compiling APK with buildozer for Android (NDK and SDK)

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I am trying to generate an APK using buildozer. The following shows the specs in my buildozer.spec file and my computer specifications:

```
python 2.7,
Buildozer 0.35
kivy 1.10.1

buildozer.spec file

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 24

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 18b

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path = ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =
```

At first, I used `android.minapi = 21` but I realized API 23 was not installed so I used API 24 as my `android.minapi` because I have API 24-29 installed and all the Android SDK build tools have also been installed. Yet I keep getting the following errors which complains about the NDK. Could someone please guide me on what to do?

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 28
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 28 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/bunmalik/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER: r18b
[WARNING]: NDK API target was not set manually, using the default of 21 = min(android-api=28, default ndk-api=21)
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r18b
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[ERROR]:   Asked for dist with name myapp with recipes (kivy, python2) and NDK API 0, but a dist with this name already exists and has either incompatible recipes (hostpython2, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python2, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy) or NDK API 19
[ERROR]:   No compatible dist found, so exiting.
```